# Is it possible to have TPH inheritance with overlapping column usage in the subclasses?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

**Entities**

```
public abstract class Person
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
  public string Discriminator { get; set; }
}

public class Friend : Person
{
  public string HomePhone { get; set; }
}

public class Family : Person
{
  public string CellPhone { get; set; }
}

public class Colleague : Person
{
  // No home phone
}
```

**Mappings**

```
public class PersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
  public PersonMap()
  {
    Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("First_Name");
    Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("Last_Name");
    Property(t => t.WorkPhone).HasColumnName("Work_Phone");

    Map<Friend>(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("Friend");
    Map<Family>(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("Family");
    Map<Colleague>(m => m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("Colleague");
  }
}

public class FriendMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Friend>
{
  public FriendMap()
  {
    Property(t => t.HomePhone).HasColumnName("Home_Phone");
  }
}

public class FamilyMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Family>
{
  public FamilyMap()
  {
    Property(t => t.CellPhone).HasColumnName("Home_Phone");
  }
}
```

**Note**:  `ColleagueMap` has no mapping for `"Home_Phone"`

**DbContext**

```
public override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  ...
  modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonMap());
  modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FriendMap());
  modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FamilyMap());
  ...
}
```

Entity Framework is telling me that I cannot map two properties to the same column:

> System.Data.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid.  Errors:
>   Each property name in a type must be unique.  Property name
>   'Home_Phone' was already defined.

I can't find any examples of TPH inheritance where multiple subclasses map different properties to the same columns.  Is this possible in EF?

Comment: You do realize that you have an inconsistent object model to begin with, don't you? I wouldn't expect (or even appreciate) an ORM to support this.

Comment: My problems go far beyond the inconsistency shown here but that isn't really relevant.  I'm not at liberty to change the root causes which is why I'm asking if its possible to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no. Each property must have its own column. It is not possible to map multiple properties in inheritance hierarchy to the same column.

Comment: it is now possible!

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with EF6 see: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/583